# I have a specialized hard rock serial number 00910344. How can I find out what year it is and what kind of history it has?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I'm trying to figure out the year of my Specialized hard rock and it's  history.

Comment: Hi, serial numbers are mostly useless in identifying bikes as they are often generic and manufacturers usually don't have public databases. You may read https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question to update your question and you will probably get some more information about the bike, like (approximate) model year and possibly even the exact model. What do you need the "history" for?

Comment: A photo would be the single most useful thing you could add with an [edit]  Nice clear clean photo from the bike's right hand side, and additional photos showing logos and decals and relevant labels.

Comment: Do you mean history like a CarFax? If so there is nothing like that for bicycles. While history is nice to know most of what you need to know about a bicycle can be observed by an experienced eye. Sometimes your local bike shop has a person with such an eye.

Answer (score 4):

Specialized's ***Hardrock*** model was first introduced in around 1987 as a fully rigid, with cantilever brakes, and the rear located under the chainstay.  Probably a 3x5 for 15 gears.

[image]
 <sub>From https://www.pedalpedlar.co.uk/products/u-gb-m1v-50cm-specialized-hardrock-c-1987-vintage-american-mountain-bike</sub>

---

The model name continues for decades.

**1995** shows a relocated rear brake, and perhaps some slightly larger diameter tubes in the frame.    The fork shows slightly less curve so not a lot of change over time.  The head tube looks longer, but this is a 23" frame and some of that comes from being larger than the other examples.

[image]
 <sub>From https://bikesheaven.com/1995-specialized-hardrock-23-blue/</sub>

---

**1999**  Last of the steel frames?  The fork stanchions with their accordion booties lasted to the mid-late 2000's on lower end bikes, but mid-higher ones like this dropped them soon after.  Or they fell off.

[image]
<sub>From https://bikewhistle.com/whistle-blog/1999specializedhardrock</sub>

---

**2000** Seems this one is a super small frame at 17".  The significant change here is the frame is now aluminium, and the welds are much more pronounced.  The large increase in tube diameter makes the bike look even smaller.  But those are still 26" tyres same as all the previous examples.   The saddle cover pictured also contributes to the size distortion.

The aluminium tubes in the frame are all straight, but flare in opposite directions most noticeably in the downtube.  Aluminium wasn't trusted as much in the early days of AL frames, so they went with larger diameter tubes which were still lighter than steel for similar strength results.

[image] 
<sub>From https://m.indiamart.com/proddetail/brand-new-2000-specialized-hardrock-hr-mtb-bike-medium-25385789262.html</sub>

Curiously, both this 2000 and the following 2009 have disk caliper mounts visible on the fork, but neither is equipped with disk brakes.

---

**2009** model, a hard tail with rim V brakes and a triple.  The frame shows more hydroforming, with curves to the downtube.

[image] 
<sub>From https://www.specialized.com/nz/en/hardrock-sport/p/22410?color=30789-22410</sub>

---

**2012**   At first glance, a very similar overall design to the 2009.  But this one's got 29" wheels, and this one shows a setup with disk brakes.

[image]
<sub>From https://www.specialized.com/nz/en/hardrock-sport-disc-int/p/35013?color=80264-35013</sub>

---

**2014**   At first glance, a very similar overall design to the 2012.

[image]
<sub>From https://www.naturalhigh.co.nz/2013/10/hardrock-29er-2014/</sub>

---

**2017** Copy-paste - really nothing significant here.  This example is a 650B wheelset.   Still rocking the triple crank too.

[image] 
<sub>From https://www.specialized.com/nz/en/hardrock-disc-650b/p/115367?color=208573-115367</sub>

And that's the latest year of release I can find for this model.  Thus it had a 30 year run.

Comment: I'm sure there are plenty of other photos, and its possible that some of these years are misrepresented or misremembered.   Please feel free to make additions with further info.

Comment: I cry when I see the "upgrade" to suspended fork in the year 2000: unneccessary complexity added, to make up for the unpleasant rigidity of aluminium frames.

Comment: This retrospective is a nice history of the Hardrock and it's also a nice snapshot of the history of hard tailed mountain bikes.